# htaccess | mod_rewrite | redirect to URL domain parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am migrating an ASP web site into WordPress. Currently, I am fixing the 404 errors, from the old website to the new but I have find a URL that looks like the following

```
http://www.mysite.com/www.customer-web-site.com
```

and I like to redirect this domain to

```
http://www.customer-web-site.com
```

currently I have use the following rewrite rule, but with no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^(www\.([^\.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3}))    http://$1    [R=301,L]
```

but this, redirect me to

```
http://index.php/
```

Can somebody help me ?

Kind regards

Comment: What about human-readable URLs? Are they turned up? As far as I remember, Wordpress uses htaccess to redirect /some-cool-hru to /index.php.

Comment: yes they are enabled. Note that I am trying the rewriterule above the WordPress rewrite rules block, so my code is not affected by the WordPress directives

Comment: And what about $1 in the rewrite rule? Does changing it to $0 fixes this?

_"$1 to $9 provide access to the grouped parts (in parentheses) of the pattern, from the RewriteRule which is subject to the current set of RewriteCond conditions. $0 provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern."_ [apache mod_rewrite doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: !!! That was cool !!!: ) I didn't used the $0, so now it works perfect !! :) If you like, post an answer to up vote you :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Posted it up, so you can close this and other people will see that this question was already answered and don't spend their time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what about $1 in the rewrite rule? Does changing it to $0 fixes this?

> $1 to $9 provide access to the grouped parts (in parentheses) of the
>   pattern, from the RewriteRule which is subject to the current set of
>   RewriteCond conditions. $0 provides access to the whole string matched
>   by that pattern.

[Apache mod_rewire doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_rewrite.html)